# PHP 7.2 is enabled but does not execute on my website

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server, php

I've just reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04 and I have 2 websites that I want to put on it. I've installed Apache2, PHP 7.2

I have my site installed on this path: `/var/www/html/benshepherd.me`

I have added this file (benshepherd.me.conf) to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName      benshepherd.me
    ServerAlias     www.benshepherd.me
    DocumentRoot    "/var/www/html/benshepherd.me"

    CustomLog       /var/log/apache2/benshepherd.me-access.log common
    ErrorLog        /var/log/apache2/benshepherd.me-error.log
    <Directory /var/www/html/benshepherd.me>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have run `a2ensite benshepherd.me`, I have run `a2enmod php7.2`

I have created a file that will run `phpinfo()` and that works correctly.

Yet when I go to my website, the line of code `<?php include('includes/styles.php'); ?>` will not execute, it comes out as html output instead.

Comment: Does 
> created a file that will run phpinfo()

mean that you are running that file on the command line `php` and it works? or it works when served through apache? Because the command line php is entirely separate from apache's php.

Comment: @Uberfuzzy I created the file and put `<?php phpinfo();` inside of it and that works but not my website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am an idiot.

I had an index.html file in the same directory as index.php

:|

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your apache config (either main or any of the various sub includes depending on your server platform) has a line like this:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Comment: It has this in that line in `/etc/apache2/mods-available/php7.2.conf` file

Comment: Oops, I lied it has this:

Comment: <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(ar|p|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>